# How to run redis keys commands on RDB file?

Tags: redis, nosql

is it possible to run redis's `keys` comannd directly on rdb dump?

```
keys "locations*" /path/to/dump.rdb
```

If its not natively supported. Wondering if any third-party tool supports this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To analyze and manipulate the contents of a Redis RDB file you should look into the extremely useful [redis-rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools).